# SEO optimization by related content search  

Tags: seo, website-design, site-search

My case is like this:

In a product page there is related products section and we pick products from same category. Simple SQL query , no magic magic

Is it any better to execute similar documents query on full text search instead of this? for both user and SEO? eg: lucene/solr or db full text index

it would be like wordpress related post plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/ this way related products will contain more common keywords than current product list.

I wonder any usage of this kind of related content in a detail page is helpful for SEO?
I don't need it for users , but is it worth to do for search engines ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand how Solr/Lucene is related to your question.

Comment: actually it is not related but just a sample to compare. I will update the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you are going to want to take the product description and remove all of the commonly used words, such as "that", "the", or "and", from the product description. Next you are going to want to take the remaining words to build your query. Here is an example of the query structure:

```
SELECT *,
MATCH (product_name, product_description) 
AGAINST ('puppies kittens rabbits ... hippos') AS score
FROM products_table 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5
```

I would recommend keeping the number of words you use to compare against other products below 20 to reduce the amount of strain on your mysql server.

Comment: sorry about misleading but my question is : 

is this helpful for seo optimization?

Comment: Sorry about that, I sometimes have a one track mind.  From what I have read and what I have seen practiced the benefit of inner linking is more to help the Google spider revisit your older content for changes.  The real benefit will be for your customers, giving them more accurate products that are close to the current product.